# force a stage to be always on top and not accessible javafx

Tags: javafx

```
stage.setAlwaysOnTop(true);
```

force the stage to be on top but still accessible so the user can press buttons again I want to make it inaccessible.

```
primaryStage.initOwner(stage);
```

does not work also.

Comment: I wonder if a simple dialog, or alert could be enough for you? (with modality set to true) Or perhaps just set your root's mouse transparency to true, if it can only be clicked (no key press or whatever)  If you elaborate a bit more on what you're trying to accomplish people here could help you more, I think.

Comment: You want it disabled? `stage.getScene().getRoot().setDisable(true);`? Not really clear what you're asking.